# Cannot find view id when implement different layout for different screen size in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, findviewbyid

I am new about fragment. i have app where implementing fragment and it has different layout. when app run in smartphone and tablet in portrait it only show one layout(with one fragment) and when in tablet in landscape it show two pane layout(with two fragments).

i am getting error when try to get view id in fragment layout. below are activity_main_screen.xml code in res/layout and res/layout-large,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is activity_main_screen.xml code in res/layout-large-land,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey">

    <fragment android:name="com.pongodev.dr.know.QuestionFragment"
              android:id="@+id/question_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" 
              android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>

    <fragment android:name="com.pongodev.dr.know.AnswerFragment"
              android:id="@+id/answer_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="2"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is fragment view question_view.xml containing button, edittext, and listview,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainScreen" 
    android:background="@drawable/app_background">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/lytSearchBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/edtSearch"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:hint="@string/type_question"
            android:textColor="@android:color/widget_edittext_dark"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_style"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:singleLine="true"/>
        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:padding="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView 
            android:id="@id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fadeScrollbars="true"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="3dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lytSearchBar"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is QuestionFragment.java code,

```
public class QuestionFragment extends ListFragment {
    OnQuestionSelectedListener mCallback;
    ImageButton btnSearch;
    QuestionListAdapter qla;

    public interface OnQuestionSelectedListener{

        public void onQuestionSelected(int position);
    }

    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_view, container, false);
    //list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);

    prgLoading = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.prgLoading);
    txtAlert = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtAlert);
    btnSearch = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);

    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "button click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    qla = new QuestionListAdapter(getActivity());
    new getQuestionList().execute();
    //setListAdapter(qla);


}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // When in two-pane layout, set the listview to highlight the selected list item
    // (We do this during onStart because at the point the listview is available.)
    if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.answer_fragment) != null) {
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception.
    try {
        mCallback = (OnQuestionSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Notify the parent activity of selected item
    mCallback.onQuestionSelected(position);

    // Set the item as checked to be highlighted when in two-pane layout
    getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
}

public class getQuestionList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    getQuestionList(){
        if(!prgLoading.isShown()){
            prgLoading.setVisibility(0);
            txtAlert.setVisibility(8);
        }
    }

    @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //parseJSONData();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        prgLoading.setVisibility(8);
        if((Question.length > 0)){
            setListAdapter(qla);
        }else{
            txtAlert.setText(R.string.no_connection_alert);
            txtAlert.setVisibility(0);
        }


    }
}
    }
```

when i try to get button id in QuestionFragment the app get error. how to fix this error?

**UPDATE**: i do not know why, suddenly my button id problem solve. but, there is other problem with ProgressBar id and TextView id. here is the logcat.

```
01-08 21:53:34.942: E/AndroidRuntime(23579): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 21:53:34.942: E/AndroidRuntime(23579): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pongodev.dr.know/com.pongodev.dr.know.MainScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-08 21:53:34.942: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
01-08 21:53:34.942: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
01-08 21:53:34.942: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
01-08 21:53:34.942: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
01-08 21:53:34.942: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-08 21:53:34.942: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-08 21:53:34.942: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
01-08 21:53:34.942: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 21:53:34.942: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-08 21:53:34.942: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
01-08 21:53:34.942: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
01-08 21:53:34.942: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-08 21:53:34.942: E/AndroidRuntime(23579): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-08 21:53:34.942: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at com.pongodev.dr.know.QuestionFragment$getQuestionList.<init>(QuestionFragment.java:140)
01-08 21:53:34.942: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at com.pongodev.dr.know.QuestionFragment.onCreate(QuestionFragment.java:97)
01-08 21:53:34.942: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1437)
01-08 21:53:34.942: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:877)
01-08 21:53:34.942: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
01-08 21:53:34.942: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
01-08 21:53:34.942: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
01-08 21:53:34.942: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:551)
01-08 21:53:34.942: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1137)
01-08 21:53:34.942: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4475)
01-08 21:53:34.942: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1943)
01-08 21:53:34.942: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: post stack trace, define "error"

Comment: I have updated my question and add the logcat.

Comment: apparently (but that's just what the stacktrace says), there is something null at QuestionFragment$getQuestionList.<init>(QuestionFragment.java:140)

Answer (score 0):

Your need to ensure all Views are initialised before running code against them. As njzk said getQuestionList is throwing hence prgloading or txtAlert is null so move the code that accesses getQuestionList from OnCreate to an overridden onActivityResult. (Fragment lifecycle -https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#Lifecycle)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. yes you are right. i forgot to initialized the view.